# std::map implementation very inefficient in gcc 4.7.2 compared to VS2013?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc, c++11

Can someone help me to understand how the std::map container is implemented? I have an class that contains atomic members and I have no need to invoke a copy constructor so I use the c++11 delete operator to suppress implicit generation of the copy constructor.

```
MyCalss(const MyClass& a) = delete;
```

This has worked fine with my windows build, however in Linux I am greeted with an error informing me that the [] operator of the std::map class is trying to invoke a deleted function.

There seems to be a major difference between the Windows VS2013 and Linux GCC 4.7.x implementations of map. This led me to do an experiment regarding how an object is inserted into a map.

I wrote this small example program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class TestItem {
public:
TestItem () { 
    _name = "TestItem" + id();
    cout << "Constructing " << _name << endl;
}
TestItem (const TestItem & other) {
   _name = "TestItem " + id();
   cout << "Copying " << other._name << " to new  " << _name <<endl;
}

string id() 
{
   static int id = 0;
   char buf[2];
   sprintf_s(buf, "%d", id++);
   return string(buf);
}
~TestItem(){
   cout << "Destroying " << _name << endl;
}
void doStuff()
{
   // stub
}

string _name;
};

void run()
{
   cout << "making new obj" << endl;
   TestItem a;
   cout << endl << endl;

   map<string, TestItem> TestItemMap;
   cout << "Makeing new obj as part of a map insert" << endl;
   TestItemMap["foo"].doStuff();
   cout << endl << endl;

   cout << "adding a value to the map" << endl;
   TestItemMap["new foo key"] = a;
   cout << endl << endl;

   cout << "looking up a value that has already been inserted" << endl;
   TestItem& b = TestItemMap["foo"];
   cout << endl << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   run();
}
```

In Windows when I run this program I get the following output:

```
making new obj
Constructing TestItem0

Making new obj as part of a map insert
Constructing TestItem1

adding a value to the map
Constructing TestItem2

looking up a value that has already been inserted

Destroying TestItem1
Destroying TestItem0
Destroying TestItem0
```

This is what I would expect to see, internally when I write

```
 TestItemMap["foo"].doStuff();
```

I would expect that map would create a new instance of TestItem and then insert it in to the RedBlack Tree by internally linking the tree node to the new TestItem.

However when I run this same code in Linux the results are very different

```
making new obj
Constructing TestItem0

Making new obj as part of a map insert
Constructing TestItem1
Copying TestItem1 to new TestItem2
Copying TestItem2 to new TestItem3
Destroying TestItem2
Destroying TestItem1

adding a value to the map
Constructing TestItem4
Copying TestItem4 to new TestItem5
Copying TestItem5 to new TestItem6
Destroying TestItem5
Destroying TestItem4

looking up a value that has already been inserted

Destroying TestItem0
Destroying TestItem3
Destroying TestItem0
```

This would indicate to me that the [] operator is creating a new instance of TestItem then calling the external map.insert() function and then destroying the newly created TestItem, and that only explains one of the calls to the copy constructor. Is the c++ stdlib in gcc really this inefficient?

Is there some standard trick that people use to overcome this problem?

Comment: The standard library used by default by GCC is called [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) and is open source. Comes with the GCC source as well. If you want to know how it's implemented, just download the source and see it.

Comment: Side note: This would indicate to *me* that your program exhibits undefined behavior as soon as more than 10 items are constructed.

Comment: You are comparing both compilations with optimizations enabled, don't you?

Comment: As for your problem, I would be more curious about the *two* lines stating `TestItem0` is destroyed.

Comment: sprintf_s is not standard so it does not compile on linux. What code did you use ?

Comment: that sprintf_s compiles under linux? that suprises me

Comment: I'd also wonder why no new item were created or copied when you do `TestItemMap["mooky"]` as you have no element with the key `"mooky"` in the map at that point in time.

Comment: Joachim, I am more interested in trying to understand the implementation choices made in libstdc++ vs the VS stdlib implementation I can see what it is doing. I want to understand wny

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is the result of the apparently unconsidered assignment operator used for `TestItemMap["new mooky key"] = a;`, which I bet the OP didn't see coming.

Comment: Come David, in the linux version I use sprintf rather then sprintf_s, but that should have no effect on the way the map inset works. Note changed the ket names from my example program to remove the name "mooky" haha in to sound a bit less silly, I forgot to change that one, I am going to edit the source to match what I ran.

Comment: @user2952015 Likewise, i did the same with my `clang` rig, and its output is similar to the VC output, save for the reference elimination gcc did for the lookup that was optimized out entirely. Thus I have one more construct and destroy .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug that was fixed with GCC 4.8.

- [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b30eb121476270d) it works with GCC 4.8
- [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/647a12de26ac483a) it fails to compile with GCC 4.7

Comment: I daresay it's not a GCC bug, but _instead MSVC is not working properly_. An implicitly-declared move constructor is not generated in presence of a user-declared copy constructor. Therefore, GCC is not to blame for not being able to use move semantics -- user has told it not to. (don't ask me why version 4.8 "works", though)

Comment: @Damon The new element is default constructed in-place and then the value is assigned, I actually fail to see where the element is/should be copied. The bug, AFAICT, would be that GCC 4.7 required copy-constructibility internally while adding the new element when instantiating `operator[]`, which is not required/allowed by the standard.

Comment: @Damon I think it's likely that it's an internal `Node` struct (or something similar) inside the `std::map` that is being move-constructed, with the effect that the user's copy-constructor is avoided.

Comment: @TristanBrindle No, neither copy- nor move-constructor should be needed, the node should use the default-constructor and construct the new element in place. This is what both VC and GCC 4.8 are doing. They then return a reference to this new element from `operator[]` and an assignment happens, see the examples I linked.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I fixed up that horrible `sprintf_s` thing:

```
string id() 
{
   static int id = 0;
   std::stringstream s;
   s << id++;
   return s.str();
}
```

and also changed your "looking up value that has already been inserted` to actually do what it says [EDIT: and so did you :-) ]

Now, compiling with g++ 4.8.1 in C++03 mode, I get a result similar to yours. But compiling with `-std=c++11`, I get

```
making new obj
Constructing TestItem0

Making new obj as part of a map insert
Constructing TestItem1

adding a value to the map
Constructing TestItem2

looking up a value that has already been inserted

Destroying TestItem0
Destroying TestItem1
Destroying TestItem0
```

It seems that MSVC is automatically using C++11 features (move semantics most likely) to give a nice performance boost, whereas you need to explicitly tell g++ to do the same.